# How to proceed to get PIN from admob without waiting to receive PIN through address post?

Tags: android, admob

I integrated admob in android application and I reached threshold. it displays a message that, Your payments are currently on hold because you have not verified your address is there any way instead of waiting for many weeks to receive PIN from admob for  address verification?

I have noticed that for adsense, https://support.google.com/adsense/contact/id_verification?hl=en to submit address proof to save many weeks to recieve PIN.
Similarly for admob, is there any link to attach address proof? or I want to wait for many weeks to receive PIN?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After the failure of 3rd application for PIN, admob will give you a link automatically for uploading proof to verify your identity.After that, you will be identified in 24 hours.

Comment: There is link. Nobody is getting a link!!!

Answer (score 2):

google is not providing link for uploading proof and there help link is not available.